# Взять позицию элемента относительно родителя

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как взять позицию элемента относительно родителя.
`position: absolute;` не подходит.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log($("#child").position().left);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rod" style="width: 500px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid;">
<div id="child" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; left: 108px; background: red; position: relative;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11634823/379949) ответа.

```js
var childPos = obj.offset();
var parentPos = obj.parent().offset();
var childOffset = {
    top: childPos.top - parentPos.top,
    left: childPos.left - parentPos.left
}
```